# Connecting to a Polar H7 Heart Rate Monitor from WP8

Tags: bluetooth, windows-phone-8, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any way to connect to Bluetooth Low Energy devices from Windows Phone 8? e.g. Heart Rate Monitors such as the Polar H7.

Some background I've tried:

- I've seen this sample for Windows 8 - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Bluetooth-Generic-4f4ea968/view/Discussions - which seems to require quite a deep level of knowledge.
- I've seen this closed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224392/nokia-lumia-920-and-bluetooth-low-energy-devices
- I've implemented WP8 Bluetooth support for Sphero myself (see https://github.com/slodge/BallControl/)
- I've read about other SPP level code - e.g. http://metroeeg.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home&ANCHOR#GettingStarted - this seems to say 'As a rule WP8 apps can only speak to paired devices.' - but I can't find any way to pair my HRM with my Lumia 920

I can't seem to find any information about WP8 and Bluetooth LE devices. Are these supported? Can WP8 talk to my Polar H7 Heart Rate monitor?

Answer (score 6):

Currently Windows Phone only supports the RFCOMM protocol over Bluetooth 2.0. The device minimum hardware spec currently doesn't include BT4.0 LE - even though some of the devices support it, it doesn't feature in the APIs. This is because the health devices using BTLE support the GATT protocol, and the current proximity stack using RFCOMM allowing scenarios such as Serial Port Profile support.

This leaves us with devices such as Sphero, and MetaWatch able to connect to the phone - but unfortunately not the latest generation of health and fitness device.

Polar do currently make a BT 2.0 heart rate monitor if you want something to pair to your 920 :)

Comment: Please make sure to vote for WP vNext BT LE support @ http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/3419027-bluetooth-4-bluetooth-low-energy-api-support-

Answer (score 2):

With the new Windows 8.1 update, it is possible to connect the Polar H7. I am using a Nokia Lumia 920 with Endomondo. It works the same as any other bluetooth device, so on a Windows Phone you first need to Pare it. Go to the Bluetooth settings and it should be visible. If you have used the Windows 8.1 Developers preview you need to downgrade to Windows 8 first and then install the official release.

Answer (score 0):

The Polar Wearlink+ bluetooth transmitter is NOT CONNECTABLE to Lumia 920 or any other Windows phone.

See: Transmitter_with_Bluetooth__Compatibility">http://www.polar.com/en/support/FAQs/Polar_WearLink_Transmitter_with_Bluetooth__Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

as of the Windows phone update 8.1 support for the H7  ( and presumably  other BT LE devices)is working correctly this has been tested in the adidas micoach application ( available through the windows store) on a nokia Lumia 920