# Getting data out of Polar H7 using BTLE using Win7

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to develop a simple app that runs on a PC that takes the polar H7 heart rate data and prints it on the screen. I am trying to find the easiest way to achieve this. The best would be use the Win8 APIs to do this but couldn't find a sample code that does this.

As an alternative, I thought about purchasing a BTLE dongle that can be accessed via USB and use the API to get this data out. Any idea what would be the best hardware to do this? Something with the simple API and robust.

Comment: here's a similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734522/connecting-to-a-polar-h7-heart-rate-monitor-from-wp8

Comment: Not really a duplicate, as Windows Phone is a more limited environment than a Windows 7 system, in particular the availability of USB ports.

Comment: Have you had a chance to open source your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same work.
I suggest this:

texas BLE dongle CC2540

Bluegiga BLED112 dongle
http://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/bled112-bluetooth-smart-dongle/

And bluetooth.org:
https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfileViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.profile.heart_rate.xml